# How to replace the top 1% of the data with a new value in R?

Tags: r

In `R`, given a  set of numerical data, how do I decide the top 1% of these data, and replace them with a new value, say, e.g. $10^{10}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this:

```
### x will be whatever variable you want to do this to. I'm replacing 
### the top 1% with 1e10. 
qnt = quantile(x,.99)
w = which(x >= qnt) 
x[w] = 1e10
```

More generally implemented as a function:

```
### x is the input data. This function replaces the top 'perc' percent
### with the value 'rp'. 
replace.top = function(x, perc, rp)
{
   qnt = quantile(x,1-perc)
   w = which(x >= qnt) 
   x[w] = rp
   return(x)
}
```

Comment: Or, even more concisely (densely) as a one-liner `x[x>=quantile(x,0.99)] <- 1e10`.

Comment: (+1) As a function: `replace.top <- function(x,p,r) { x[x>=quantile(x,1-p)] <- r; x}`

Comment: (+1, cardinal) Is there anything more computationally efficient about what you've written (or are there just bonus points for making it a single line)?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the internals of $R$, but my guess is that the version in the comment is probably slightly more efficient, though the difference would likely only be noticeable if (a) the function were called a very large number of times in a loop or (b) `x` was, itself, very large. I haven't tested that, though; I'd be curious to know. The code in your answer is, of course, a lot easier on the eyes. :)

Comment: Note also that if there are a very large number of ties in `x`, then basing the replacement on quantiles might not work as expected. An alternative would be `x[rank(x,ties.method="first")>=(1-p)*length(x)] <- r` but in the "typical" case where the values of `x` are fairly "continuous", I think the previous approach using quantiles is better.

Comment: The answers and comments above are good answers.  Depending on what the questioner is ultimately looking for @Luna may also be interested in the literature on winsorized means and variances and that there are several implementations in various R packages (eg in Wilcox's WRS package associated with his excellent book Modern Statistics for the Social and Behavioral Sciences.)

Comment: I tried a quick simulation today and found something curious. Using as input `x = rnorm(1e5)` I found that the one-liner runs about 15% faster than the version in the answer. The difference in running times is essentially entirely attributable to the `which` call. However, I also found that the code `replace.top <- function(x,p,r) { q=quantile(x,1-p); x[x>=q] <- r; x}` appeared to run a tiny bit faster than the original one-liner. Finally, it's important *not* to use `replicate` in the `system.time` call. I found this amounts to simply testing R's memory manager, which is pretty poor.

Comment: The call I used was `system.time( for(i in 1:N ) y <- replace.top(x,0.01,5) )` with $N = 10^4$.